# How to clear a textarea with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="message">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="send_message" placeholder="Enter text ...">  </textarea>
      <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">OK</a>
      <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">Cancel</a>

</div>
```

I want to clear the textarea contents when I click the cancel button. I have:

```
$('#message').on("click", "a", function(){
    if($(this).is(":contains(Cancel)")) {

      $("#send_message")(
                  function(){
                  $(this).val('');

                }
                );

    } 
    else if($(this).is(":contains(OK)"))  {
                ......
    }
});
```

but this doesn't do anything. How can I fix this.

Comment: i think its  $(this).html("")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('#message').on("click", "a", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":contains(Cancel)")) {
        $("#send_message").val('');
    } else if ($(this).is(":contains(OK)")) { // other code

    }
});
```

### Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/b7w7q/)**

In your code you used the selector `$("#send_message")`, you cannot just add a `function` after that way.The `$(this)` you referred in that "wrong placed" function you already "have" by using the id selector. So I used your idea and corrected some things on your code to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a bug in your line. It should just be:

```
$("#send_message").val("")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle that does what you need. http://jsfiddle.net/PsWHJ/

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="message">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="send_message" placeholder="Enter text ...">  </textarea>
      <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">OK</a>
      <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">Cancel</a>
</div>


$('a','#message').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).text() === 'OK'){
        alert('Process Form');
    }else{
        $('#send_message').val("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way...

```
$('#message').on("click", "a", function () {
    var jqEl = $(this);
    if (jqEl.text() == "Cancel")) {
        jqEl.prevAll('textarea').val('');
    } else if (jqEl.text() == "OK") { 
         //Do other stuff...
    }
});
```

Hope it helps